# How do I convert unstandardized RMR estimates into standardized RMR estimates?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, structural-equation-modeling, amos, rmr

I am having difficulty turning unstandardized RMR estimates from AMOS software output in a SEM into standardized estimates to enable suitable interpretation. Can someone give me advice on where to start with this?

Comment: I found these, don't know if it helps: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21477535 and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21480170

Comment: This will be pretty tricky. The RMR is based on covariances, the SRMR on correlations. If you can persuade AMOS to analyze a correlation matrix, that will work.

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe refers to the website which says "Note that the SRMR is undefined when there are missing values in the data." Every other SEM package (of which I am aware) will give SRMR with missing data.

Answer (score 1):

In AMOS there is a plug-in that calculates SRMR for you.
Across the top there is a "Plugins" drop down menu, and the SRMR plug-in is there.